# Boost.Regex expression build

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I need to build an expression which matches generic `#include "file.h"` code line.

Is the following correct for that purpose?

```
([[:blank:]]*#include[[:blank:]]*")([[:print:]]*\.h)([[:print:]]*)
```

The expression should match for the followings:

```
#include     "header.h" //first include

     #include "header2.h"      //second include

#include "header3.h"
```

I use boost regex library.

Comment: http://www.regextester.com/ try it out...

Comment: Could you explain what dialect I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost Regex can use Perl, Or POSIX regular expression syntax : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax.html

So you can check and test your regex here: http://www.regextester.com/

Just set to preg (perl) if you are using the default behaviour of boost (See above).